# How to translate query from SQL to MongoDB C# Driver: Like, Distinct and Top

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

My SQL query looks like:

```
from attr in Attributes
where attr.Value.Contains("444")
select attr.Value).Distinct().Take(100).ToList();
```

I have tried with something like that but i dont know where use the "SetLimit(n)" function here:

```
IMongoQuery likeValueQuery = Query.Matches("Value", "/444/");
var result = Attributes.Distinct("Value", likeValueQuery);
```

Regards.